# how save line-break on localStorage using text() jQuery method

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to do a dabblet inspired app using jQuery for practice, here is the repo: https://github.com/thinkxl/docss and here the live demo: http://thinkxl.github.com/docss/

I'm using localStorage, so when the user load the page, I want to call the info

```
render: function(){
        css.text(cssDB);
        html.text(htmlDB);
        result.html(htmlDB);
    },
```

I use the text() method because if I use html() the HTML field display something like 'something' instead of

```
<div>something</div>
```

so everything is cool here, but when I recall everything at the load, everything is displayed on one line, I want to keep the line-breaks.

How wold I do that?

Comment: Replace instances of \n with <br/> ?